# How to search public or private API's in `nm` tool for all the libraries in the binary .ipa

Tags: ios, itunes, ipa, nm

Today my app got rejected by Apple for the below reason :

> Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs, which is a
>   violation of the App Store Review Guidelines:
>
> `'setUploadFileURL:'`
>
> The use of non-public APIs is not permitted in the App Store because
>   it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.

**Also  they suggested `nm` tool along with [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/nm.1.html) dead link for "nm tool" Xcode manual page.**

All right, now I was started searching for the API `setUploadFileURL` but not found. then from otool I am  failed to get all the libraries linked to app

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool:
>   can't open file:  (No such file or directory)

Then for the `nm` tool, I have dead link and no idea where the library will reside ! I have got .ipa file along with Payload.

Please anyone help ?

Comment: you have more than one xcode installed ?

Comment: No, current Xcode version is 7.3

Answer (score 7):

1. `cd ...`
2. `grep -r xxx .` (like：`grep -r mhr_requestHasComplete .`)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Create an [Ad Hoc Deployment](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html) and try:

```
unzip AppName.ipa
```

then either

```
otool -L Payload/AppName.app/AppName
```

or

```
nm Payload/AppName.app/AppName
```

Comment: yes, this will list the libraries or  the symbols. From this, how can we detect the private APIs ?